# Unexpected overload resolution in visual studio involving void*, string and const char[]

Tags: c++

I got following unexpected overload resolution behavior with the visual studio compiler (tested in VS2010 and VS2012).

Minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void f(void *)
{
    std::cout << "f(void*)\n";
}

void f(const std::string &)
{
    std::cout << "f(const std::string &)\n";
}

int main()
{
    f("Hello World!");
}
```

Output:

```
> f(void *)
```

Expected Ouptut:

```
> f(const std::string &)
```

Compiling with GCC(tested with 4.6.3) generates the expected output.

If I comment out the "const std::string &" version of f(), visual studio happily compiles on /W4 without any warnings, while GCC emits following error (as expected): "invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]".

Does anyone know why visual studio behaves in that way, choosing basically a const cast overload over a conversion to std::string for char[]?

Is there any way to prohibit this behavior, or at least get VS to generate a warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For [VS 2013 Microsoft documents silently dropping `const` for string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) as a Microsoft-specific behavior for C++:

> Microsoft Specific
>
> In Visual C++ you can use a string literal to initialize a pointer to
>   non-const char or wchar_t. This is allowed in C code, but is
>   deprecated in C++98 and removed in C++11.
>
> ...
>
> You can cause the compiler to emit an error when a string literal is converted to a non_const character when you set the `/Zc:strictStrings` (Disable string literal type conversion) compiler option.

For versions earlier than VS 2013 (for example [VS 2012's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), Microsoft documents string literals in C++ as using the C convention of being non-const array of `char`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why it is unexpected.  The conversion of `char
const[]` to a `std::string` involves a user defined conversion;
the conversion to `void*` doesn't.  And a conversion involving
a user defined conversion is always "less good" than one which
doesn't involve a user defined conversion.

The real issue here is that C++ doesn't have a built-in string
type, and the string literals don't have type `std::string`.
The normal solution is to provide an overload for `char const*`
as well:

```
void f( void* );
void f( std::string const& );
inline void f( char const* p ) { f( std::string( p ) ); }
```

This additional overload will pick up string literals.

(As a general rule: anytime you're overloading: if one of the
overloads is for `std::string`, provide one for `char const*` as
well, if any are for arithmetic types, provide one for
`int`, to catch integral literals, and if any are for a floating
point type, provide one for `double`, to catch floating point
literals.)

Comment: +1 (especially for the general rule), but I *can* see why it's unexpected; because it also relies on the unfortunate `const`-dropping conversion from string literal to `char*`.

Comment: The issue in the question is the conversion to pointer to non-const, which shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: @Angew But the const-dropping is still not a user defined conversion.  (In a more general context, I can see why it is unexpected, because logically, string literals and `std::string` are strings, and one doesn't think of a conversion being necessary.  Alas, for historical reasons...)

Comment: @JamesKanze I know, but even if one's aware that string literals are not `std::string`s, it's still confusing that MSVC applies the `const`-drop without so much as a warning.

Comment: @interjay Yes.  I'd missed the non-const.  This conversion only applies to string literals, and as been dropped from C++11 (unless they moved the text allowing it to somewhere else).

Comment: @Angew That is a bit of a surprise, since it was deprecated in earlier versions, and has been completely dropped in C++11.  On the other hand, VC++ has always been a bit lax with regards to rules concerning const; it's only very recently that they stopped accepting binding a temporary to a non-const reference.

Comment: GCC allows the implicit conversion of a string literal to `char*` (in both C++03 and C++11 mode), but not to `void*`. I don't know if it should be allowed or not.

Comment: @interjay My reading is that it shouldn't be allowed: "This
conversion is considered only when there is an explicit
appropriate pointer target type,[...]" (C++03, §4.2/2).  I would
interpret "appropriate pointer target type" to mean a `char*`
(and only a `char*`) for a narrow string literal.  At any rate,
C++11 bans it completely, even for a `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

The apparent issue is, as noted by others, that MSVC allows implicit conversion from string literals to non-`const` `char*`, and thence to `void*`.

I say apparent because your `void*` overload should be a `void const*` overload, as it does not change the pointed to data.  Doing so will make things 'worse', as calling it with a string literal will now unambiguously select the `void const*` overload.  However this illustrates what is going wrong: `""` is a `char const(&)[1]` (an array of `const char`), not a `std::string`, and `char const(&)[1]` is closer related to pointers than to `std::string`.  Relying on the overload picking `std::string` over a pointer is fragile, even on gcc, as making your code `const` correct breaks it!

To fix this we can write a greedy overload for `std::string`.

```
template<typename S, typename=typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<S,std::string>::value>::type>
void f(S&&s){
  f(std::string{std::forward<S>(s)});
}
```

with the above two overloads left intact (except `const` added).

Or (better) via tag dispatching:

```
void f(void const* v, std::false_type){
  std::cout << "f(void*)\n";
}
void f(std::string const& s, std::true_type){
  std::cout << "f(const std::string &)\n";
}
template<typename T>
void f(T&&t){
  return f(std::forward<T>(t), std::is_convertible<T,std::string>() );
}
```

both of which are ways to do manual function overload dispatching, biased towards `std::string`.

[live example](http://ideone.com/ax8JvE)

Note that `std::string` literals are now possible in C++, but I would advise against requiring them on the basis of fragility.

Comment: @dyp good point.  Ambiguous in terms of programmer intent then?

Comment: Yeah, maybe. It's either quite a subtle overload resolution (and therefore error-prone) or not expressing the intent of the programmer.

Comment: Btw. there's another typo in `coid f(std::string const& s, std::true_type){ blah }` (shall I fix those kind typos?)

Comment: @DyP Sure, but really I should compile my answers.  :)  I need to find a good way to set up a compiler on my phone, or a web compiler that works well on a phone (many of them have quirky edit boxes that don't play well with touch screen browsers).